# Getting following error which push a file to gcloud bucket

Tags: github-actions

`` Error: google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage failed with path should be a `path.relative()`d string ``

Here is my yml workflow configuration:

```
    - name: 'upload file'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage@v0'
        with:
          path: /tmp/test.txt
          destination: bucket_name/test.txt
```

Comment: `/tmp/test.txt` is an absolute path, not relative.

Comment: relative is also not working

Comment: Please edit your question for that scenario

Answer (score 0):

It has version issue it worked with version 0.7.0